# Not able to perform form action after updating of input values

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use an email service from formspree that uses input format :

```
<form
  action="https://formspree.io/f/*formendpoint* "
  method="POST"
>
  <label>
    Your email:
    <input type="email" name="email">
  </label>
  <label>
    Your message:
    <textarea name="message"></textarea>
  </label>
  <!-- your other form fields go here -->
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

As this allows only two inputs. so I am using one form to take multiple inputs and update the input values of another form which will perform the formspree function. But the following code is unable to perform the task.

html:

```
<main>
        <div class="container">
            <p class="specialtext">Contact ME!</p>
            <form  class="contactform" id="firstForm">
                <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" required>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail" required>
                <input type="text" id="phoneno" name="phone" placeholder="Phone No.">
                <textarea name="message" id="message"  placeholder="Message" cols="30" rows="10" required></textarea>
                <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
            </form>

            <form action="https://formspree.io/f/xoqzgybd" method="post" id="secondForm">
                <!-- <input type="email" name="name" > -->
                <input type="email" name="email">
                <textarea name="message" id="" cols="1" rows="1"></textarea>
            </form>

        </div>
    </main>
```

Script:

```
let firstForm = document.getElementById('firstForm');
let secondForm = document.getElementById('secondForm');
let emailInput = document.querySelector('#secondForm input[name="email"]');
let messageInput = document.querySelector('#secondForm textarea[name="message"]');

firstForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    
    let emailtext=document.querySelector( '#email' ).value;
    let messagetext = document.getElementById('name').value + "/n" +
        document.getElementById('phoneno').value + "/n" +
        document.getElementById('message').value;

    emailInput.value = emailtext;
    messageInput.value = messagetext;

    secondForm.submit();
});
```

I want the action of second form performed with updated values.`your text`

Comment: `let messageInput = document.querySelector('#secondForm input[name="message"]');` won't select anything, you do not have an `input` element with the name `message` in your second form. `input` != `textarea`

Comment: And using `type="number"` for a phone number field is just absolutely wrong. Phone numbers are _not_ numeric values. This should be a normal text input, or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/tel

Comment: I fixed those things but it's still not doing anything

Comment: _"but it's still not doing anything"_ - yes, it is. Watching what happens in the browser console and network panel (tools _you_ can use in your browser as well, btw.), the second form clearly does get populated and submitted. What it then fails on, is actually _making_ the request to `https://formspree.io/`, because the system behind that is presenting an invalid SSL certificate, so that the browser blocks the request.

Comment: Thank you for the time. There was some issue with my js file while importing something. It's resolved now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have spell all the inputs and outputs correctly.

Here is a simpler script that is easier to debug

```js
let firstForm = document.getElementById('firstForm');
let secondForm = document.getElementById('secondForm');
let emailInput = document.getElementById('email');
let emailOutput = document.getElementById('email1');
let messageOutput = document.getElementById('message1');

firstForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  emailOutput.value = document.getElementById('email').value;
  let messagetext = [];
  messagetext.push(document.getElementById('name').value);
  messagetext.push(document.getElementById('phoneno').value);
  messagetext.push(document.getElementById('message').value);
  messageOutput.value = messagetext.join("\n");
  secondForm.submit();
});
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <p class="specialtext">Contact ME!</p>
    <form class="contactform" id="firstForm">
      <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" required>
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail" required>
      <input type="text" id="phoneno" name="phone" placeholder="Phone No.">
      <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message" cols="30" rows="10" required></textarea>
      <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</main>

<form action="https://formspree.io/f/xoqzgybd" method="post" id="secondForm" hidden>
  <input name="email" id="email1">
  <textarea name="message" id="message1"></textarea>
</form>
```